# How can I get coordinates of two points simultaneously touched on screen in Android?

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I want to know that is it possible to get two correct set of coordinates point when the screen is touched simultaneously on to points on screen .
If yes than how can this be used. Googled it but didnt got any satisfactory result.Please help?

Comment: Well you may save all touch event occured in the last X milliseconds and on each new touch event you check if the last touch happened within a threshold of Y seconds to the actual one. If this condition applies, they happened "at the same time".

Comment: I just didnt got it!!can you clarify!!

Comment: **onTouch**: saveTimeStamp and Coordinates (This might be your first touch) **onAnotherTouch**: saveTimeStamp and check if it almost happened at the same time as the first one. Do you know how I mean it? I think it never happens that your finger will hit the screen at the same time, so you also want to recognise events as 'simultaneous' if the are happening shortly after each other.

Comment: that's a good idea i think i would try it..thanx

Comment: It is even easier: Within the onTouch event use MotionEvent.getHistoricalEventTime(pos) to check the time difference to the last touch! Just found it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) hope this works ^.-

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getX and getY, use the following two methods:

```
public final float getX (int pointerIndex)
        Since: API Level 5

        Returns the X coordinate of this event for the given pointer index (use getPointerId(int) to find the pointer identifier for this index). Whole numbers are pixels; the value may have a fraction for input devices that are sub-pixel precise.


public final float getY (int pointerIndex)
        Since: API Level 5

        Returns the Y coordinate of this event for the given pointer index (use getPointerId(int) to find the pointer identifier for this index). Whole numbers are pixels; the value may have a fraction for input devices that are sub-pixel precise.
        Parameters
        pointerIndex    Raw index of pointer to retrieve. Value may be from 0 (the first pointer that is down) to getPointerCount()-1.
```

Comment: checkout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerId%28int%29 this link will help you to understand what is pointerIndex in above code